# Using Combobox with BindingSource and reuse it on Add New click of Binding Navigator

Tags: c#, bindingsource

I have a huge information displayed on a `winform` around 50 `textboxes` along with 2 `Comboboxes`. I am using `BindingSource` to fill the information in the `form`. The info is filling good in `textboxes` and in `comboboxes` also. The problem I am facing is that when I click the `ADD NEW` button all the `textboxes` go blank and the `comboboxes` also go blank(no value). Logically it is true because the `dataset` is now ready for a new information input. I can input the info in the `textboxes` but what about the `comboboxes`?? How can I fill those `comboboxes` with specified values to select and also the info should be updated by clicking `SAVE` button on the `BindingNavigator`. Right now if I click the `SAVE` button, only the `textbox` values are being saved not the `combobox` values as they are empty. Any Help will be greatly appreciated because I am really stuck into this thing...

Comment: Load the combo boxes with the values you need to save. Or allow user to input values in to the combo boxes.

Comment: @Irshad the comboboxes are being loaded by the bindingsource. How can I rebind them so that they have values I need.